# Cursor replacement

Tags: sql

I would like to have a SQL based query that would replace a cursor-based SQL stored procedure. The main requirement is to look for the value of the next row data and replace the higher value. For e.g The Hi Value field (Hi) will compute the previous row and give the new output of NewHi.

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a simple running max():

```
select yyymm, hi, max(hi) over (order by yyyymm) as newhi
from the_table
order by yyyymm;
```